# Custom Directive : Dropdown selected value not binding

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a custom directive for a drop down control in AngularJS 1.4.4.  I can handle the selected event, but i can not get the binding for what is selected in the drop down list.

I want to call this from Html markup the following way.

```
<my-dropdown-list source="myList" destination="mySelection"  />
```

The angular js custom directive is here.

```
(function() {

var directive = function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=source',
            selectedValues: '=destination'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {

            $scope.onSelChange = function() {
                alert('called');
                console.log($scope.selectedItem.Code, $scope.selectedItem.Name);
            };
           // $scope.selectedItem is always undefined here.


        },
        link: function ($scope, $elem) {

            var rowHtml =
            '<select ng-options="item as item.Name for item in model" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="onSelChange()"></select>';

            $elem.html(rowHtml);
            $compile($elem.contents())($scope.$new());
        }
    };
};
my.directive('myDropdownList', directive);
})();
```

I'm new to Angular, so this may be something small that i missed here, but i can't seem to get a value for 'selectedItem'

Comment: It's the classic "dot notation" problem. You need to have your binding properties on an object - `myModel.mySelection` to have it bind with a directive.

Comment: The problem is that you created a new scope for the html you've added to your directive template. But in controller you have access to its parent scope and the parent scope can not see its child.

Answer (score 0):

I find out this in AgularJS document

> Note that the value of a select directive used without ngOptions is
>   always a string. When the model needs to be bound to a non-string
>   value, you must either explictly convert it using a directive (see
>   example below) or use ngOptions to specify the set of options. This is
>   because an option element can only be bound to string values at
>   present.

Link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

You should use ngRepeat to generate the list like this post:
[Angularjs: select not updating when ng-model is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211573/angularjs-select-not-updating-when-ng-model-is-updated)

Comment: I tried using ng-repeat first, with the same problem. I think it is the parent scope cannot see the selected binding, as a comment above suggested.