# AngularJS - A dropdown is not retaining the selected values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS web application,

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/x9uIx5Inkxxt3fqttkkK?p=preview

One of my drop down (First) is not retaining the selected value.
The html code fragment is below.

I know it is something to do with the mapping **ng-model="entityPropertyType.propertyId"**

The **entityPropertyType** is a iterated value from the list.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="entityPropertyType in advancedSearch.entityPropertyTypes" >

        <label class="control-label col-md-1">Business Card</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="entityPropertyType.propertyId" 
                ng-change="businessCardSelected($index, entityPropertyType.propertyId)" >
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option ng-repeat="property in businessCards" value="{{property.propertyId}}">{{property.propertyLabel}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211573/angularjs-select-not-updating-when-ng-model-is-updated/26211704#26211704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use ngRepeat to render select options. Use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-options="property.propertyId as property.propertyLabel for property in businessCards"
        ng-model="entityPropertyType.propertyId" 
        ng-change="businessCardSelected($index, entityPropertyType.propertyId)">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/v6KbJSkqu5XNz2LUfbrK?p=preview