# Angular 4 Select don't update on ngModel change

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select, ngmodel

I am trying to make that after new value is selected, I call eventChange() function and restore selected value to default. But what happens: ngModel value updates, but selected value stays the same. How should I do that selected value and ngModel value would be the same?

HTML file

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
       (change)="eventChange()"

>
      <option [disabled]="true"
              [ngValue]="-1">
        Choose an option
      </option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of myList index as i"
              [ngValue]="i"
      >
        {{item.name}}
      </option>
</select>
```

Function from Component file

```
selectedValue = -1; //works //Option in select is changed
eventChange(){
    this.selectedValue= -1; //don't work 
    //Function is called, 
    //Value changes
    //But selected Option in Select doesn't change
}
```

Comment:
On running web page(refresh) first value of select is set properly, if in component file I set variable **selectedValue** to other index the other value is selected, but it works only on run, but not in function)

Also I found this question [Angularjs: select not updating when ng-model is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211573/angularjs-select-not-updating-when-ng-model-is-updated)
But here is an answer to AngularJS for using ng-options, instead of ng-repeat, in angular 4 I found only *ngFor...

Update:
Clarification just in case: function is being called, but I want change selected option through javascript. I try this by changing ngModel value, but even when ngModel value is cahnged, selected option doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ngModelChange** and you don't need **`[ngValue]`**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
       (ngModelChange)="eventChange()"
```

Comment: Somehow still not working. Function is always called in both ("change" and "ngModelChange") events. But ng-model =selectedValue is one index, and selected value is item that has other index.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want change selected option through javascript . I try this by changing ngModel value, but selected option doesn't change.

Comment: remove ng-value and use only ngModel