# NgModel doesn't update in select input

Tags: angular, select, ngmodel

I have a problem when I want to update the selected value of a select input with my typescript code. I have not found anything related to this as the problem is quite specific.

In my example, I want to have a select input for a list of countries. But this input can be updated dynamically since the last option allows you to add a new country.

Here is the HTML file :

```
<label for="select_country">Pays</label>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"
        id="select_country"
        (change)="check_country()">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" >{{ country }}</option>
  <option >Nouveau pays</option>
</select>
{{ selectedCountry }}
```

The associated typescript file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CountriesService } from "../country.service"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-recette',
  templateUrl: './add-recette.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-recette.component.css']
})
export class AddRecetteComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedCountry : string = "";
  countries : string [] = [];

  constructor(private countriesService: CountriesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCountries();
  }

  getCountries() : void{
    this.countriesService.getCountries()
    .subscribe(string => this.countries = string);
  }

  check_country() : void {
    if (this.selectedCountry === "Nouveau pays") {
      this.selectedCountry = "";
      let new_country = prompt("New country ?").trim();
      if (new_country && new_country.length > 0) {
        this.countriesService.add(new_country);
        this.selectedCountry = new_country;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, the service, quite short :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CountriesService {

  countries : string [] = [
    "France", "Chine", "Nouvelle-Zélande"
  ]

  constructor() { }

  getCountries(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(this.countries);
  }

  add(newC : string) : void {
    if (!(this.countries.includes(newC))) {
      this.countries.push(newC);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is :
When I try to select a country, it's fine.
When I try to add a new country, it's fine.
When from France, I try to add China, it detects that it is already in the array, so it doesn't add it and just point to China, so it's fine.
But when from France, I try to add France, the selectedCountry is updated to France so it's ok but the select option now shows us `Nouveau pays` which is not what it is supposed to do since `this.selectedCountry` equals France.
More generally, adding a country that is already in the list doesn't update the select input if the select input was previously on it.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634129/angular-4-select-dont-update-on-ngmodel-change?rq=1) but the solution given doesn't work with me.

The behaviour is very surprising. What do you think about it ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You havn't provided value in option?

Comment: I have heard that it is optional with NgModel. If I add it, the problem remains anyway.

Comment: And use == instead of === in this.selectedCountry === "Nouveau pays".

Comment: @Prachi: I would strongly advise against that.